# missing artifact com.oracle:ojdbc:jar:12.2.0.1 error in pom.xml

Tags: eclipse, maven

I do have ojdbc8.jar files in my maven dependencies still it shows as error in pom.xml. Why is it so?

[these are my maven dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDV7g.png)

[this is pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rX6S5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have a dependency with artifactId `ojdbc8` and version `19.3.0.0`, but your POM is looking for an artifact with artifactId `ojdbc` and version `12.2.0.1`. The version is probably inherited from some parent POM or BOM.

So you have the wrong jar with the wrong version.